# New way of finding primes - Can it be proven wrong?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

So, I believe I may have discovered a new way for finding primes, but I'm not sure if there is a definite proof; If not, then I have just created my own one.

Anyway, this new method I've come up with is that you take any integer above $0$, $x$, and times it by $1$ and add $1$, then times it by $2$ and add $1$, then times it by $3$ and add $1$, etc, all the way up to $(x^{2} +1)$

$(x +1), (2x +1), (3x +1), (4x +1), ... ,(x^{2} +1)$

My conjecture is that at least one of these terms will give you a prime number, when $x$ is any integer above $0$.

Is there any way to prove me right/wrong?

Comment: How far have you checked this?

Comment: I have checked this to 100

Comment: This is equivalent to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80865/least-prime-in-a-arithmetic-progression).  (well, that question refers to prime $x$ but it mentions the general problem as well).  It appears that little is known, though there are some much weaker bounds on the least prime in that progression.

Comment: How would this imply the Goldbach Conjecture?

Comment: It could at least find a way to find primes that has been 100% guaranteed, which might in some way help prove/disprove the Goldbach Conjecture. Not exactly sure, but you never know

Comment: @JakubSkop Even if we could prove that one of those numbers must always be prime, I do not see any relation to Goldbach , sorry.

Comment: That really doesn't make sense.  For instance, [Bertrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) tells that, starting from any natural number $n$, there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$.  There's a finite set with $n$ elements which always contains a prime.  No relevance to Goldbach that I can see.

Comment: @lulu in fact Bertrand's postulate is a necessary condition for Goldbach. $$2n=p+q\land n+n=2n\implies n+n=p+q\\\implies n-p=q-n\land p>2\implies q-n<n-2\implies q<2n-2$$

Comment: OK ok, sorry for even bringing it up; all I'm really interested in is a proof.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A194945

Answer (score 3):

This site

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem

shows what has been found out for the least prime in an arithmetic progression. The conjecture $$p(a,d)<d^2$$ would imply that you can always find a prime this way, but this has not been unconditionally proven.

For Goldbach's conjecture we need two numbers which are simultaneously prime, so even if we can always find primes this way, there is no guarantee that they can be summed up to a given even number. I cannot see a way to use this approach for solving Goldbach's conjecture.

Answer (score 0):

$$n\equiv-(x^{-1})\bmod p$$ are knocked out as lead coefficients. They create a number divisible by p any time p is not a factor of x. That means just 57 survive for x=100, p<10 and only 23 survive that for x=101 . Accounting for overlap is really the only tricky part for me. I count it wrong without code.